# getting exception: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo

Tags: android, exception

i'm getting the following exception: `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cs.workshop.solvedroid/cs.workshop.solvedroid.SolveCaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException`

when i run the application, get to the MainMenuActivity and try to open the SolveCaptureAvctivity i get the exception.

i've other Qs about this exception but they all point to the AndroidManifest.xml and it
seems fine to me. what can it be? please help

```
public class SolveCaptureActivity extends Activity {
```

Button bCamera;
    ImageView captured_image = ( ImageView ) findViewById( R.id.image_capture_photo);

```
private static final int PICTURE_REQUEST = 0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.solve_capture);
    Log.e("mydebug", "ERROR ERROR ERROR");
    /*
    // "Back" button 
    Button bBack = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_back);
    bBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoBack = new Intent();
            setResult(RESULT_OK, gotoBack);
            finish();
        }
    });
    */

    // "Camera" button
    bCamera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_camera);
    bCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent camera = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);   
            startActivityForResult(camera, PICTURE_REQUEST);
            int caemraRequestCode = 0, CameraResultCode = -1;
            Intent data = new Intent();
            try{
            onActivityResult(caemraRequestCode, CameraResultCode, data);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("mydebug", "ERROR ERROR ERROR");
            }


        }

        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            Log.d("mylog", "here1");
            Log.d("mylog", Integer.toString(requestCode));
            Log.d("mylog", Integer.toString(resultCode));
            if (requestCode == PICTURE_REQUEST) {
                Log.d("mylog", "here2");
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
                    // Display image received on the view;
                    Log.d("mylog", "here3");
                    Log.d("mylog", "here4");
                    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");                   
                    if (photo != null) { // Display your image in an ImageView in your layout (if you want to test it)
                        Log.d("mylog", "here5");
                        ImageView pictureHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_capture_photo);
                        pictureHolder.setImageBitmap(photo);                             
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });


}
```

}

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);


    // "Solve Capture" button
    Button bSlvCapture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainmenu_solvecapture);
    bSlvCapture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoSolveCapture = new Intent(v.getContext(), SolveCaptureActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(gotoSolveCapture, 0);
        }
    });

    // "Solve Manual" button
    Button bSlvManual = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainmenu_solvemanual);
    bSlvManual.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoSolveManual = new Intent(v.getContext(), SolveManualActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(gotoSolveManual, 0);
        }
    });

    // "About" button
    Button bAbout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_mainmenu_about);
    bAbout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent gotoAbout = new Intent(v.getContext(), AboutActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(gotoAbout, 0);
        }
    });
```

}
}

08-07 18:33:23.854: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed cs.workshop.solvedroid/.MainMenuActivity: +4s385ms
08-07 18:33:26.784: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { cmp=cs.workshop.solvedroid/.AboutActivity } from pid 330
08-07 18:33:26.984: DEBUG/dalvikvm(330): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 11K, 53% free 2582K/5379K, external 7607K/9499K, paused 51ms
08-07 18:33:28.434: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Displayed cs.workshop.solvedroid/.AboutActivity: +1s68ms
08-07 18:33:29.104: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(330): No keyboard for id 0
08-07 18:33:29.104: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(330): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
08-07 18:33:30.674: INFO/ActivityManager(70): Starting: Intent { cmp=cs.workshop.solvedroid/.SolveCaptureActivity } from pid 330
08-07 18:33:30.834: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(330): Shutting down VM
08-07 18:33:30.834: WARN/dalvikvm(330): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{cs.workshop.solvedroid/cs.workshop.solvedroid.SolveCaptureActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1544)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at cs.workshop.solvedroid.SolveCaptureActivity.(SolveCaptureActivity.java:15)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1536)
08-07 18:33:30.874: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(330):     ... 11 more

```
manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="cs.workshop.solvedroid"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".MainMenuActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="AboutActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SolveCaptureActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="SolveManualActivity"></activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="ManualSolutionActivity"></activity>

    </application>
manifest>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `findViewById()` until after `setContentView()` is called.